# SQL - Having Count

Tags: sql, count, having, having-clause

I am fairly new to SQL.
I am trying to solve the following question:
Which supplier offer at least 20 plants and where the delivery time is less than 17 days.
Show the supplier code and the number of distict plants.
The supplier with the most plants is on top.

This is what I have (however I get no result).

```
select  levCode, artCodeLev
from Offertes
where levertermijn < 17 
group by artCodeLev, LevCode
having count(LevCode) > 20
```

Comment: The question is vague since it seems like one supplier can have multiple delivery times. Your query finds all suppliers that have more than 20 plants that have a delivery time of less than 17 days, not that have 20 plants AND a "delivery time" of less than 17 days. Can you clarify that part?

Comment: Also some sample data (even just a few records) would be good to know what `artCodeLev` and `LevCode` represent.

Comment: When posting database-related questions its good practice to supply some sample data or at least how your table/db is set up in terms of columns and such. Then explain what you're trying to achieve and then add code you've already tried. You've done the last two but are missing the sample data/show how you've setup table/db in terms of columns and what they represent. Then we can accurately help and answer.

Comment: I think I just found the answer: select Levcode, count(ArtCodeLev)
from Offertes
where levertermijn < 17
group by levCode
having count(LevCode) > 20

Comment: I should have used count(ArtCodeLev) in the select statement

Comment: If you've solved it on your own either close the question or write up an answer and answer your own question and accept the answer ^_^ that way anyone can future benefit from it.

Comment: I would go for "having count(*) > 19" to keep the intent of the Count clear to all developers involved (aka your future self) , since your counting rows and not Codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
select Levcode, count(ArtCodeLev) 
from Offertes 
where levertermijn < 17 
group by levCode 
having count(*) > 20
```

Comment: count(*) >= 20.